# Transfer labels ("tags") from a SMB share to an AFP share

Tags: finder, applescript, afp, smb, metadata

I had a SMB share from my NAS (based on illumos aka OpenSolaris, I used the kernel CIFS) and now I installed Netatalk for better performances.

The metadata apparently cannot be read back, that means that I lost custom folder icons (not many, already solved) and finder labels ("tags" in Mavericks).
I am trying to use AppleScript to set them back.

I have the same shares mounted at the same time, from a UNIX point of view they are:

```
/Volumes/share
/Volumes/share-1
```

depending on which one I mounted first. On the desktop they appear with the same name (and same icon, shame on Apple this time).

I tried AppleScript:

```
display dialog "Select SMB share/folder"
set SMBshare to choose folder
display dialog "Select equivalent AFP share/folder"
set AFPshare to choose folder
```

but I get for both "share:Selected folder". As consequence, I cannot go on with:

```
set theLabel to label index of SMBshare
if theLabel is not 0 then
    [do some search/replace to get new path and set label index]
end if
```

So, how could I avoid the issue and transfer the labels from one share to another?

The only idea left is to mount the SMB share, then obtain the full list of files using

```
set {TempTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, ", "}
tell application "Finder" to set MyList to (entire contents of (choose folder)) as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TempTID
```

and then unmount the SMB share, mount the AFP share, reapply all the labels previously saved.

**Update**

I tried the method of mounting/unmounting and it works, but only on small folders or shares, on bigger ones the "get entire contents" takes too long and there is a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a shell script instead of AppleScript. A tool like [this](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) can list and change tags on files.